# Laravel: how to make pagination when you get json data from controller in javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel

let's say i have json data coming from my controller, that data is paginated I want display pagination result inside the javascript.

I mean...I want to use the links() method inside javascript but pagination not appearing... is it ok to write it inside javascript or what?.

Here's the data coming from the controller:

**Controller**

```
public function getPaginatedData(Request $request)
{
     // some data goes here

     $output = '';
     $data = DB::table('schedules')
                        ->where('station_id', $stations_id)
                        ->paginate(2);
     foreach($data as $row)
     {
        $output .= '
          <tr>
              <td>'.$row->id.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->schedule_number.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->route_name.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->user_first.'</td>
              <td>'.$row->created_at.'</td>
              <td> <a style="margin-left: em; " href="' . url('schedule/' .$row->id .'/edit') . '">
                        <button style=" font-size: 1em; width: 4.5em; height: 2.5em;"  type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit
                         </button>
                   </a></td>
              <td> <a style="color: white; margin-left: em;" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" onclick="deleteData('.$row->id.')" 
                        data-target="#delete_confirm" class="btn btn-danger">
                      Delete
                    </a></td>
           </tr>
        ';
     } 

     $records = array(
            'output'  => $output,
            'schedules'  => $data
     ); 
     echo json_encode($records);

}
```

so here what i tried when i get the json from controller in javascript

**Javascript**

```
success:function(records)
{
     console.log(records.output);
     $('tbody').html(records.output);
     $('#pager').html(' <ul class="pager">'+ records.schedules.links +'</ul>');
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Schedule_number</th>
                <th>Route</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>Created_at</th>
                <th>edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>

     </tbody>
</table>
<div id="pager">

</div>
```

when i run the above code nothing appears... is there any solution to my promblem, guys? thanks!

Comment: you should use json_encode

Comment: still, same ouptut the pagiation not appearing

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of sending all the data along with html from controller function, You can just send JSON data. as shown below

$data = DB::table('schedules')
                        ->where('station_id', $stations_id)
                        ->paginate(2);
return $data -> toJson(); 

This json response will also include your pagination links.
You can use these links in your blade file
I hope it will work
```